# Not able to debug the spring boot application jar

Tags: java, spring-boot, debugging

I want to debug my springboot application and ran it with following command but it does not running in the debugging mode, it just running in the normal execution mode ( I tried to attach a debugger from eclipse and it failed)

`java -jar my.jar -Dagentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=8000`

I chekced the starting logs and it does not have anything related to debug mode there

```
2019-07-12 17:53:36.627  INFO 34585 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2019-07-12 17:53:36.714  INFO 34585 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2019-07-12 17:53:36.715  INFO 34585 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/9.0.13
2019-07-12 17:53:36.770  INFO 34585 --- [           main] o.a.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener   : The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: [/Users/nadeeshtv/Library/Java/Extensions:/Library/Java/Extensions:/Network/Library/Java/Extensions:/System/Library/Java/Extensions:/usr/lib/java:.]
2019-07-12 17:53:37.179  INFO 34585 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2019-07-12 17:53:37.179  INFO 34585 --- [           main] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 3439 ms
2019-07-12 17:53:37.622  INFO 34585 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2019-07-12 17:53:37.781  INFO 34585 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.w.s.WelcomePageHandlerMapping    : Adding welcome page: class path resource [static/index.html]
2019-07-12 17:53:38.014  INFO 34585 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2019-07-12 17:53:38.018  INFO 34585 --- [           main] c.a.b.t.springboot.Application           : Started Application in 6.361 seconds (JVM running for 8.006)
```

Could someone please tell what am I doing wrong?

Please find my spring boot application class

```
@SpringBootApplication()
public class MyApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public WebServerFactoryCustomizer<TomcatServletWebServerFactory>
    containerCustomizer(){
        return new EmbeddedTomcatCustomizer();
    }

    private static class EmbeddedTomcatCustomizer implements WebServerFactoryCustomizer<TomcatServletWebServerFactory> {
        @Override
        public void customize(TomcatServletWebServerFactory factory) {
            factory.addConnectorCustomizers((TomcatConnectorCustomizer) connector -> {
                connector.setAttribute("relaxedPathChars", "<>[\\]^`{|}");
                connector.setAttribute("relaxedQueryChars", "<>[\\]^`{|}");
            });
        }
    }
}
```